# Find the eigenvalues of A and a basis for each eigenspace of A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ =
>   $$
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         -4 & -4 & 0 \\
>         2 & 2 & 0 \\
>         2 & 2 & 0 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   Find the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of $A$

I've got the eigenvalues to be $0$ and $-2$, and I have got the eigenspaces corresponding to the eigenvlues to be

For $0$ = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1  \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

For $-2$ = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2  \\
        1  \\
        1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

However the solution says the eigenspace for $0$ is $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0  \\
        0 \\
        1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ and $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1  \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Why is it that?

Comment: The zero eigenvalues value is a double eigenvalue and has two eigenvectors associated with it

Comment: Ah I see, but where does the [0,0,1] come from?

Comment: Has your class gone over generalized eigenvectors? This is normally covered under such a thing, alternatively note that when you plug in zero for the eigenvalue, the last component of any vector multiplied by this matrix is left undermined leading to more free variables than you accounted for

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Triatticus There’s no need to invoke generalized eigenvectors here. The third column of $A$ tells us that $A(0,0,1)^T=0$ (recall that the columns of the matrix are the images of the basis), so $(0,0,1)$ is an eigenvector of $0$. You could also directly compute a basis for the kernel (nullspace) of $A$ via row-reduction and discover that it’s two-dimensional.

Comment: Hence the second part of my comment doesn't concern generalized eigenvectors, I merely stated that in the sense of repeated eigenvalues this is where that comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenspace relative to $0$ can be deduced from the RREF of the matrix, which is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This shows there are *two* free variables; the only equation is $x_1+x_2=0$, so a basis of the eigenspace is obtained by first choosing $x_2=1$ and $x_3=0$, then $x_2=0$ and $x_3=1$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors. The last column of $A$ tells us that the image of $(0,0,1)^T$ is zero, so it is an eigenvalue of $0$.

The result of right-multiplying a matrix by a column vector is a linear combination of its columns. We can see that subtracting the second column from the first gives zero, so the image of $(1,-1,0)$ is zero, which means that it, too is an eigenvector of $0$. This vector is not a multiple of $(0,0,1)^T$, so we know that $0$ has both algebraic and geometric multiplicities of at least two, and that these vectors can form part of a basis for its eigenspace.

The sum of the eigenvalues, taking into account their multiplicities, is equal to the trace of the matrix. Here, $\operatorname{tr}A=-4+2+0=-2=-2+0+0$, which gives us the third eigenvalue. I’ll leave finding a corresponding eigenvector to you.